# Azure Build Agent - Open Docker Port 2375

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I try to migrate my java maven project to Azure Build Pipeline. I use the https://dmp.fabric8.io that requires the port 2375 to be open on the Docker host.

In Docker Desktop, there is a setting for that:
[image]

My build fail with that message:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.43.4:build (docker-build) on project aaaaaaaaaa: Cannot create docker access object : Connect to localhost:2375 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused`

Does somebody know where i can open that port in the azure build?

Comment: Enabling that option is a giant massive huge security hole, especially on a native-Linux host: anyone who can connect to the port can trivially root the host system, and you _never_ want to make it network-accessible.  You should be able to use the default `dockerHost` setting, which will use a Unix socket by default.  What in your application is configured to require the extremely insecure setting?

Comment: @DavidMaze I could figure out how to change this on linux => <dockerHost>unix:///var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>, but i can not make it work on my local windows maschine. Do you have an idea how this could look like? i tried many thinks. eg <dockerHost>npipe://./pipe/docker_engine_windows</dockerHost>

Comment: May I know what you mean by `migrate my java maven project to Azure Build Pipeline`? Are you using a Windows machine to host the docker app? And Azure pipeline is running on this machine as a self-hosted agent for build or deployment? What is the command/task that you use in the pipeline and will it reproduce the same error if running the command/workflow on that machine locally (i.e. without running via pipeline agent job)? It seems more likely a docker environment configuration query rather than caused by Azure Pipelines. This check can help isolate the issue.

Comment: Hi there, Glad to know you have found a solution. Would you consider mark your answer, which may help others with similar concerns? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution :-). I put this `<dockerHost>unix:///var/run/docker.sock</dockerHost>` as a replacement for that `<dockerHost>http://localhost:2375</dockerHost>`.

Here are the answers for @alvin

> May I know what you mean by migrate my java maven project to Azure
> Build Pipeline?

I use to run my maven build on a jenkins, know we try to run it on Azure in Cloud.

> Are you using a Windows machine to host the docker app?

I am using the provided Build Agents in Azure DevOps, i am not 100% sure, but i think they are linux.

> What is the command/task that you use in the pipeline and will it
> reproduce the same error if running the command/workflow on that
> machine locally (i.e. without running via pipeline agent job)?

Locally i run on a Windows with Docker Desktop, there i use `<dockerHost>http://localhost:2375</dockerHost>`. That works fine. In the Pipeline on Azure i had the problem.

Here is the Pipeline:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- script: echo Hello, world!
  displayName: 'Run a one-line script'

- script: |
    echo Add other tasks to build, test, and deploy your project.
    echo See https://aka.ms/yaml
  displayName: 'Run a multi-line script'

#- task: JavaToolInstaller@0
#  inputs:
#    versionSpec: '17'
#    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
#    jdkSourceOption: 'PreInstalled'


  # Maven Authenticate v0
  # Provides credentials for Azure Artifacts feeds and external maven repositories.
- task: MavenAuthenticate@0
  inputs:
    mavenServiceConnections: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa-maven-releases


  # Starter pipeline
- task: Maven@4
  inputs:
    mavenPomFile: 'pom.xml'
    goals: 'clean install'
    publishJUnitResults: true
    testResultsFiles: '**/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'
    javaHomeOption: 'JDKVersion'
    jdkVersionOption: '17'
    jdkArchitectureOption: 'x64'
    mavenVersionOption: 'Default'
    mavenAuthenticateFeed: false
    effectivePomSkip: false
    sonarQubeRunAnalysis: false
    sqMavenPluginVersionChoice: 'latest'
    findBugsRunAnalysis: false
    spotBugsRunAnalysis: false
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml
```

The only thing i don't know yet, is how to change locally on windows the  away from 2375 Port. But maybe i will solve that later.